# Сравнение строк java через equals

Tags: java, строки, сравнение, equals

Делаю примитивный калькулятор, проблема возникла в сравнении строки с операцией(+,-,*)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class calc { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter number:");
      int firnumber = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter operation:");
      String operation = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter number:");
      int secnumber = sc.nextInt();
      sc.close();
      if (operation.equals('*')==true){
        int result = firnumber*secnumber;
        System.out.print(result);   
      }
   }
}
```

Если отдельно выводить результат сравнения operation(со значением *) и *, выводит false.

Comment: Наверно, там '\n' в конце.

Comment: "==true" после equals не нужно. Метод уже возвращает true или false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одинарных кавычках - это не строка. Используйте двойные кавычки:

```
operation.equals("*")
```

И правильнее будет сравнивать вот так:

```
"*".equals(operation)
```

В этом случае, если operation будет null, вы не получите Exception, как в первом варианте.

```
String operation = "*";
Character ch = '*';
System.out.println(operation.equals('*')); //false
System.out.println(ch.equals('*')); //true
```